# animation forwards doesn't works on :hover

Tags: html, css, animation, transform

Why can't I use animation: forwards on :hover?
The animation works, but the command "forwards doesn't.

Problem:

HTML:

```
<img src="images/notebook_desk.svg" class="notebook-cover">
```

CSS:

```
.notebook-cover{
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
grid-column: 4;
margin-left: -40px;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-origin: 0 50%;
transform: perspective(2000px);
z-index: 2;
}
.notebook-cover:hover{
    animation: CoverBook 2s forwards
}
@keyframes CoverBook{    
    to{
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        z-index: 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: it doest only on hover ... you think it will stay you unhover ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve but if you want the cover to stay in its state even if it's not in `:hover` state anymore, you could use the `animation-play-state` property.

```css
.notebook-cover {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  grid-column: 4;
  margin-left: -40px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: perspective(2000px);
  z-index: 2;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  animation: CoverBook 2s forwards paused;
}

.notebook-cover:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes CoverBook {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="notebook-cover"></div>
```

Comment: i like this ... let's wait and see if this what the OP really want :)